# Cannot bulk load because the file "\\123455\Rajashekar\test.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I tried below code,

```
bulk insert #TEST 
from '\\123455\Rajashekar\test.txt' 
with (Fieldterminator=',',Rowterminator='\n',Firstrow=1)
```

i tried adding the name of the computer to the address hoping it will work but i get the following error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot bulk load because the file "\\123455\Rajashekar\test.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)

I am using SQL server 2016 with windows authentication. I have given shared folder access to everyone with full control on this folder. can anyone tell me what is wrong with query.

Comment: have you tried just the drive rather than UNC? i.e. `C:\Rajshekar\test.txt`

Comment: Have you tried accessing the network share with the user id your **server** is running?

Comment: @Scimon: I tried with C:\Rajshekar\test.txt it is working fine.But, I don't want  to load from c drive.I want to load from shared path.is that posible? if so could you please give example.Thanks.

Comment: @rajshekhar did you have any resolution to this issue?